# How to call Two APIs in a Single Function

Tags: database, api, dart

I want to get the data from database. I have 2 Apis 1: to get records information like name, address, company etc.. another one api 2: for getting ProfilePhoto. I am getting output from first api but not able to get profilePhoto Api. So how can I call both Apis in a single function? function is

```
Future<DataDetails> getData1() async {
    var id = 34;

    final response1 = await http.get(Uri.parse("Api Url"));

    if(response1.statusCode == 200) {

      var temp = DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response1.body));
      print(temp);
      return temp;
    }

    return DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response1.body)) ;
}

FutureBuilder(
                 future: getData(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return Screenshot(
                              controller: _ssController,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OntapView()));
                                },
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      width: 350,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                          // color: Colors.amber[100]
                                          color: const Color(0xffccf7ff)
                                      ),
                                      child:  Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  height: 15,
                                                  width: 200,
                                                  child: Text('${snapshot.data!.cardName} ',
                                                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                                ),
                                     SizedBox(height: 8),
                                          Row(
                                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: [
                                              CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 45,
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                                                backgroundImage: FileImage(File('${snapshot.data!.profilePhotoPath}')),        
                                              ),
                                              const SizedBox(width: 10),
                                              Container(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20,top: 10),
                                                  width: 130,
                                                  height: 100,
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text('${snapshot.data!.name} ',
                                                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                                      const SizedBox(height: 5),
                                                      Container(
                                                        child: Text('${snapshot.data!.address}',
                                                          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  )
                                              ),
```

I am new to flutter. If possible please share example code.

Comment: Please provide more information - how did you try to call the other endpoint?

Comment: @Xzenon, output side code added please check.  after getting data from db. here I am going to display.

Comment: You haven't shown us where you're calling the second endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but if you need to call another API (I'm guessing "ProfilePhoto"), you should not put any "return" before calling that API because the "return temp" and "return DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response1.body)) ;" will stop the following of your function.
If the first call for the API is the line :

```
final response1 = await http.get(Uri.parse("Api Url"));
```

That means that you should just return this response too.

It should look like that :

```
Future<DataDetails> getData1() async {
var id = 34;

// Call first api ?
final response1 = await http.get(Uri.parse("Api Url"));


if(response1.statusCode == 200) {
// Call second API ? 
  var temp = DataDetails.fromJson(jsonDecode(response1.body));
  print(temp);
// return both of variable
  return [temp, response1];
} else {
return error;
}
```

And also, does the print work ?
You can also do a print to see what response1 look like to know if the statusCode is 200

Comment: Hi @LoicJu,Thank you, I tried this code but its not working. when I applied this method my Whole code become Dead.